# How to measure precisely CPU usage in Background Tasks?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

CPU usage quota for Background Tasks in WinRT is 1 second, or 2 seconds if they are on lockscreen. The question is how to measure accurately this CPU usage - I'd like to know if my code runs under this 2 sec quota or not? I guess using just DateTime.Now before and after the execution of the task is not the right approach.
The MSDN article about Background Tasks:
[Supporting your app with background tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx)

Comment: I would also guess that an i5 can run more code than an ARM based processor... Will I so need the slowest processor avalible to test if my app will not take more than 2 sec?

Comment: Good point, if that's right, we have much less computing power for our background work on low-end ARM tablets than on Core-i7 oveclocked desktops.

Comment: Are web workers the same as background tasks? I would like to fetch and cache images, but 2 seconds doesn't seem like enough processing time (especially since I'd like to crop and save them).

Comment: Is this a single time task or will it run repeatedly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

If you start `Task Manager`, under the `App history` tab, you can see the statistics of Resource usage by various apps. One of them is `CPU Time`. The problem is that it's not the  average, but it only displays the total CPU usage time.

If you need the average time, the trick is to keep a count in your app for any background activity, and divide the whole time by that, so you will get an average time.

Comment: I guess this is the best we can do right now for measuring the CPU usage, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used [GetProcessTimes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223(v=vs.85).aspx) WinAPI.

The documentation says “desktop apps only”, but technically, it is present even on the phones:

```
    [DllImport( "KERNELBASE.DLL", SetLastError = true )]
    static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

    // NB! Undocumented API, won't pass marketplace checks.
    [DllImport( "KERNELBASE.DLL", SetLastError = true )]
    [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
    static extern bool GetProcessTimes( IntPtr hProcess, out long lpCreationTime, out long lpExitTime, out long lpKernelTime, out long lpUserTime );
```

On the PC replace KERNELBASE.DLL with Kernel32.dll.

That won’t pass marketplace certification, but should be enough for you to benchmark your background task.

Call GetProcessTimes when started, calculate `long startTime = KernelTime + UserTime`. Call GetProcessTimes when finished, calculate `( KernelTime + UserTime ) - startTime`, and you get your data. The unit of measure is 100ns ticks, just like in TimeSpan.